# Authentication failure to a private docker registry

Tags: docker, authentication

I'm stuck in Docker registry deployment tutorial. I tried to follow the basic steps as described in the documentation: I created a folder /auth in my home, then applied the followning commands:

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint htpasswd httpd:2 -Bbn login password > auth/htpasswd

sudo docker run --name registry -v "auth:/auth" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd -v "/etc/letsencrypt/":/certs/ -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/live/domain.ext/cert.pem -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/live/domain.ext/privkey.pem -p 443:443 registry:2
```

The cert config seem to run fine as I'm able to see authentication failures in the server side logs, but the authentication is always rejected regardless if the provided credentials are correct.

The output auth/htpasswd seem correct. I've read potential problems about -B for generation of auth/htpasswd, but this does not seem to be the issue here.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I'm stuck on basically the same thing